# RFECV throwing an error when using catboost as the estimator

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, catboost, rfe

I would like to utilize Catboost to perform RFECV:
Sample code here:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV

from catboost import CatBoostClassifier

def scoring_func(cl, X, Y_true):
    Y_pred = cl.predict_proba(X)[:,1]
    return roc_auc_score(Y_true, Y_pred)

kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=8888)

cl = CatBoostClassifier(
    iterations=100,
    random_seed=63,
    learning_rate=0.05,
    custom_loss='F1',
    loss_function = 'Logloss',
    class_weights = prop,
    l2_leaf_reg = 4
)
selector = RFECV(estimator=cl, cv=kf.split(X_train, y_train), scoring=scoring_func, verbose=1)

selector = selector.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

This throws the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'CatBoostClassifier' object has no attribute '_get_tags'
```

I can't seem to find any documentation that addresses this. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround was subclassing

```
class CatBoostRegressor(CatBoostRegressor):
    def _get_tags(self):
        return {'allow_nan': True}
```

But _get_tags method was merged [here](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/1282).

Still problematic is, however, the same setup but with categorical variables (for other reasons).